# How can I assign my method to a thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have written the following code:

```
var threaddatatable = new System.Threading.Thread(update);
threaddatatable.Start(dt);

update(datatable dt)
{
}
```

But I am receiving these errors:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   System.Threading.Thread.Thread(System.Threading.ThreadStart)has
>   some invalid arguments

And

> Argument 1 cannot convert from 'method
>   group' to System.Threading.ThreadStart

How can I assign my `update` method to my thread?

Answer (score 6):

The signature takes object; you need

```
new Thread(obj => update((DataTable)obj));
```

I also suggest looking at either the ThreadPool or TPL/Task - threads are relatively expensive.

Answer (score 0):

you should rewrite your code  like this

var threaddatatable = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart( update));
        threaddatatable.Start();